# unable to return data from module in express node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have written below code in one file:

**models/exported.js**

```
 module.exports = {
        processedList: function(store_name) {
            var t;
           var tradeIds = exported.find({storename: store_name}, function (err, value) {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
             return value;

            }).select('tid -_id');

        }, // Export connection here
    };
```

I have another file in routes

**routes/exported.js**

```
var exported = require('../models/exported.js');
var tradeIds = exported.processedList(storename);
    console.log('simer'+tradeIds);
}
```

but I get undefined in console.log. If instead of return statement in processedlist I write console.log then the result gets console. But my requirement is to return data from model file to route file.

I am new to express and node js.

I guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acoording to your question, you want calling a function from route and get return response from your function to route.  simple use callback functions.

**`models/exported.js`**

```
 module.exports = {
    processedList: function (store_name, callback) {
        var t;
        var tradeIds = exported.find({storename: store_name}, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
                callback("error", err)
            } else {
                callback("success", value)
            }
        }).select('tid -_id');
    }
}
```

**routes/exported.js**

```
  var exported = require('../models/exported.js');
exported.processedList('storename', function (err, results) {
    if (err == 'error') {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Simer i am just updated my code hope this works for you. last time there may be syntex error. and still any issue let me know.

Comment: Both the solutions are working, yours and kawadhiya21, But it means if I put routes/exported.js code in some function and want to call that funtion then I have to make a call back for that too.Every time we want to call another function we need to use call backs.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying sync operation in async environment. `processedList` may or may not have completed when you try to console log `tradeIds`. NodeJS would not wait for it to complete because it is asynchronous in nature (by design and it is not a bug). You can pass callback rather than executing this way.

**models/exported.js**

```
module.exports = {
        processedList: function(store_name, cb) {
            var t;
           var tradeIds = exported.find({storename: store_name}, function (err, value) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
             cb(null, value);
        }).select('tid -_id');

    }, // Export connection here
};
```

**routes/exported.js**

```
var exported = require('../models/exported.js');
exported.processedList(storename, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    console.log(results);
});
```

This makes sure that `console.log` happens only when `processedList` finishes execution.

Comment: It is working. But it means if I put routes/exported.js code in some function and what to call that then I have to make a call back for that too.Every time we have to call another function we need to use call backs.

Comment: Yes it works that way. All of javascript is asynchronous. And callback is one of the ways to channelize your tasks.